# jQuery UI slider in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, triggers, internet-explorer-9, slider

I am having this issue only in IE9.
I have a button set to change the slider value on click. However, it fails. Actually, no events are triggered on sliderchange too. Any idea how to fix this? Got the latest updates on jqueryui and jquery js libraries.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#slider_1").slider({
        value: 3000,
        min: 0,
        max: 15000,
        step: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider_1_val" ).val(ui.value);
        }
    });

$("#button_Konut").mousedown(function(){
      $( "#slider_1").slider({ value:7000 });
});

});
```

When I take

```
$( "#slider_1").slider({ value:7000 });
```

outside the mousedown (into the ready), it fires on pageload. however, in any other event (mousedown, slide of another slider, mouseup, click, anything..) it does not respond.

Any idea how to solve this for IE9?
Thanks,

Comment: Works fine in IE9 and Chrome for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rahhp/. Can you post your HTML you're using this on?

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks. Something might be wrong with my libraries or the fact that I use too many plugins might get things mixed up. I will test again.

Comment: I finally figured! One of the many css files I use for other widgets caused the problem. Specifically, in a menu-bar css file, inside body element, there was behavior:url("csshover3.htc"); Which somehow blocked ie9 triggers as I explained above. When i disable that line, everything started running smoothly. (Not sure about the implications on menu, yet. Seems to be working fine with basic usage)